# How can user get client from rest of spring boot application?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, rest

I'm trying to master Rest architecture. And I can’t understand how the user, having entered the address, will receive a client written in js. When i used thymeleaf i was transferring simple pages. But now the server is sending json packets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just create urls that return json packets. Those are called rest apis. The client on js end request the servers and get those json packets from apis and use them to show data on UI. Json becomes the format of your data transfer. Before this you were returning the entire preprocessed web page by using thymeleaf but now you leave the web page rendering part to client only and you provide the required data via those apis in json format. Just the data not the html. So there will be 2 applications in general. One is the server giving the json data via apis and other would be your UI app on client side.

Why do this? To keep them separate, light weighted, distributed and segregated. One step closer to being micro-service architecture also.

Answer (score 0):

They wouldn't.

The user (assuming they are using a web application in the first place) would visit the URL of a website which provided an HTML document with the JS for the client in it. That client would make the request to the REST API.